# Python: Trying to get audio to play at intervals

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

I am currently trying to make a metronome program. It takes the tempo the user wants and plays sounds according to that tempo.

This is the test code I wrote:

```
import winsound
import time

while True:
    winsound.PlaySound('beep.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

So the code above is suppose to play a simple beeping noise every 100 milliseconds, but when I run it I hear a delay in the sound.

For example, it should go:

Beep Beep Beep Beep Beep

But what I hear is:

Beep Beep Beep Beep (very short delay) Beep

I have tried it at many different tempos to make sure I didn't mishear the discrepancies, but it is certainly there, and it repeats at different patterns for each tempo.

What can I do to get rid of this discrepancy?

Comment: i tried you code and it's working fine

Comment: Very weird, I still hear it, even if I replace my sound with something longer. EDIT:  I had an error in the code, forgot to indent the last line, try it again?

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using Linux, I can't test the code I'm going to suggest. But what if we simply move the `time.sleep()`?

```
import winsound
import time

while True:
    winsound.PlaySound('beep.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: Very foolish of me, I missed the indent by accident.

Comment: Nope, that was the code I originally had, just mistyped it here. Still hearing the delay.